# React, react.children + react.cloneElement breaks when using spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am rendering some child routes with react router using `React.children` (for all the sub routes under a certain main route.

This has been working fine for me, however I previously was deconstructing the props I was passing into the children like so -

```
const { prop1, prop2, prop3 } = this.props;

 const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    prop1,
    prop2,
    prop3
  });
});
```

This had been working great, however more recently I started to get a lot more props so I figured I could make it much easier by just spreading props into the child object like so :

```
 const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, {...this.props});
})
```

This seemed to be ok, but I am now getting some weird behaviour in that **I can no longer see my `routeParams` (`this.props.routeParams`) from react router**.

It seems like the spread operator should do the same thing, just with less code, unless I am misunderstanding something.

When I switch it back the non spread operator approach this works fine. Any idea why this is?

Comment: I don't think you need to use spread here, try passing props as is. `React.cloneElement(child, this.props);`

Comment: @FabianSchultz same issues arise with this, this.props.routeParams doesn't update for some reason :(

Answer (score 2):

**The first argument​ of a `React.Children.map` callback function will set the `this` context of the callback ([check the docs here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children.map))**

You are setting the `this` context of `React.Children.map` callback to the value  `child` when you pass it as the first argument to the callback.

> So rather than passing **`this.props`** to `cloneElement` you are passing 
>   **`child.props.routeParams`**.

Comment: I think the fat arrow syntax gives me the outside this though, no?

Comment: Not when the argument passed into the callback is used to define `this` context

Comment: This was a good catch but I am not sure it is fixing the issue. If i do like `const props = this.props` above the map function then spread in that props variable I am still having the same issue. Maybe an issue with how react router updates it's route params to the props.

Comment: Maybe post up the rest of the code for that attempt and that of your React Router setup. You're sure that your props contains the relevant values before the map?